# how to prevent rendering when a modal button is clicked

Tags: reactjs

I have a component which displays list of jobs. Clicking on each job will open a modal and displays the details of the job. I have a list of candidates displayed in the modal and when i click a button in the modal, the component re renders and the list of candidates are populated twice. how to prevent that. I have called the props below the render() which should not be done. But don't know where to give.

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
 import history from '../history'
import moment from 'moment'
import changeStatus from '../store/actions/changeJobStatus'



class EmpJobcontent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.sendJobId = this.sendJobId.bind(this);

    }
    state = {
        jobid: '', candidatephoneno: '', statusid: ''
    }


    getJobId = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            jobid: event.target.getAttribute('name')
        }, () => this.sendJobId())

    }
    closejob = (event) => {
        // this.props.changeStatus(event.target.getAttribute("name"))

        // var x = document.getElementById("status");
        var x = event.target
        if (x.value === "close job") {
            x.value = "open job";
            x.classList.add("btn-primary");
            x.classList.remove("btn-danger");
            this.props.changeStatus(event.target.getAttribute("name"))

        } else {
            x.classList.remove("btn-primary");
            x.classList.add("btn-danger");
            x.value = "close job";
            this.props.changeStatus(event.target.getAttribute("name"))

        }


    }
    individualChat = () => {
        // history.push('/individualchat')
    }

    sendJobId = () => {
        this.props.empInfo(this.state.jobid)
    }

    applyJob = () => {
        document.getElementById("applyjob").disabled = true;
        const { candidatephoneno } = this.props
        this.setState({
            candidatephoneno: candidatephoneno, jobid: this.state.jobid
        }, () => this.sendApplyJob())
    }
    sendApplyJob = () => {
        this.props.applyJob(this.state)

    }
    render() {
        const { joblists } = this.props
        const { appliedCandidates } = this.props

        return (
            <div className=' d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-center' >
                {joblists && joblists.map(joblist => {

                    return (<div >
                        <div id='cards' ref="jobid" className="card shadow slidercard ">
                            <div className="row mt-3 d-flex align-items-center" >
                                <div className="col-md-3">
                                    <div className="profilepic  ml-3"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="text-left col-md-9 ">
                                    <h6>{joblist.companyName}</h6>
                                </div>
                                {/* <div className="col-md-3"><i className="far fa-heart heart_color"></i></div> */}

                            </div>
                            <div className="m-3">
                                <h5 className="font-weight-bold pt-3 text-left" id="jobdescription" data-toggle="modal" data-target={`#${joblist.id}`} name={`${joblist.id}`} >{joblist.Description}</h5>
                                <h5 className="font-weight-bold pt-3 text-left ">{joblist.RatePerHour}</h5>
                                <div className="row pt-3" id='cardfooter'>
                                    <div className="col-md-2">
                                        <div><i className="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="col-md-5">
                                        <h6 className="float-left">{joblist.Location}</h6>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="col-md-5">
                                        <h6 className="float-right">{moment(joblist.postedon.toDate()).fromNow()}</h6>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="modal fade show" id={joblist.id} ref="jobid" tabIndex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                            <div className="modal-dialog shadow mw-100 w-75" role="document">
                                <div className="modal-content">
                                    <div className="modal-header">
                                        <button type='button' className="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="modal-body">
                                        <div className="jobdesc">
                                            <div className="row mt-3">
                                                <div className="col-md-2">
                                                    <div className="jobdescpic ml-3"></div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div className="col-md-8 dialog_body text-left">
                                                    <h6>{joblist.companyName}</h6>
                                                    <div>
                                                        <h5 className="font-weight-bold pt-3 text-left mb-5">{joblist.Title}</h5>
                                                        <div className="row d-flex align-items-center">
                                                            <div className="col-md-9">
                                                                <div className="row d-flex align-items-center border shadow p-2 font-weight-bold " id='rateperhour'>
                                                                    <div className="col-md-4 text-center">
                                                                        <p><i className="far fa-clock"></i>1 hour </p>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                    <div className="col-md-4 text-center">
                                                                        <p>{joblist.RatePerHour}</p>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                    {/* <div className="col-md-6 ml-auto">
                                            <button type="submit" id='applyjob' className="cta btn btn-primary" onClick={this.applyJob}>apply job</button>
                                        </div> */}
                                                                    <div className="col-md-4 text-center">
                                                                        <p>{joblist.status}</p>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div className="col-md-3">
                                                                <div className="d-flex align-items-start justify-content-end">
                                                                    <h6>{moment(joblist.postedon.toDate()).fromNow()}</h6>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <p className="mt-5">{joblist.Description}</p>

                                                        {/* <img src={documentimg} alt="" /> */}
                                                        {/* <a href={joblist.Documents} target='_blank'>{joblist.labeltext}</a> */}
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>

                                                <div className="col-md-2" id="popupmenu">
                                                    <input type='button' id='status' className={joblist.status === "closed" ? "btn btn-primary" : "btn btn-danger"} onClick={this.closejob.bind(this)} name={joblist.id} value={joblist.status === 'closed' ? 'open job' : "close job"} />

                                                    {/* <ul>
                                                        <li>
                                                            <a href="/"><i className="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i></a>
                                                            <ul>
                                                                <li><Link to={`/appliedcandidates`}>status</Link></li>
                                                            </ul>
                                                        </li>
                                                    </ul> */}
                                                </div>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="modal-footer d-block">
                                        <h4 className="text-center p-3 font-weight-bold text-info">applied candidates</h4>
                                        {appliedCandidates && appliedCandidates.map(appliedCandidate => {
                                            if (joblist.id === appliedCandidate.jobid) {
                                                return (
                                                    <div className="row pb-3">
                                                        <div className="col-md-4 offset-md-1 text-left font-weight-bold">
                                                            <p>{appliedCandidate.firstName}</p>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div className="col-md-2">
                                                            <button type="button" className="btn btn-success card-btn-width">hire</button>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div className="col-md-2">
                                                            <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger card-btn-width">reject</button>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div className="col-md-2">
                                                            <button id={appliedCandidate.id} onClick={this.individualChat} type="submit" className="btn btn-info card-btn-width" data-dismiss="modal">chat</button>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>

                                                )
                                            }
                                        })}


                                    </div>



                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    )
                })
                }

            </div >
        )
    }

}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    console.log(state);
    return {
        candidatephoneno: state.candidateSignin.phoneno,
        appliedCandidates: state.getAppliedCandidates.appliedCandidate
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        changeStatus: (statusid) => dispatch(changeStatus(statusid)),

    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(EmpJobcontent)
```

Comment: `EmpJobcontent` is the modal? and which is the button that leads to re-render?

Comment: EmpJobContent is the component that has got the modal ` <div className="modal fade show" `. Any button in the modal leads to a state change and renders the component.